# Create web map from QGIS workspace

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, html

I need to know how to create a web map of one QGIS workspace. Actually I want to provide a link and share it to web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the QGIS To Web plugin? https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web

You'll have to find somewhere to host it, of course, but that plugin will help you create the web map.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the already suggested (and awesome) qgis2web, there is [QGIS Cloud](https://qgiscloud.com/), a very powerful, plugin-fed hosting service for GIS data.